# PHP function returns ZERO

Tags: php, mysql

I'm having trouble with this PHP function.  It keeps returning zero, but I know the SQL statement works because I've queried it myself.  Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?  The last line makes no sense to me...I'm editing this code that someone else wrote.  This function should return a number in the hundreds, assuming the date is in March.  Thanks!

```
    function getCountBetweenDays($day1,$day2,$service)

{

    global $conn;

    if ($service==1){

$query = "SELECT COUNT(*) as NUM FROM `items` WHERE `modified` BETWEEN '$day1 00:00:00' AND '$day2 23:59:59';";}



    elseif($service==2){

$query = "SELECT COUNT(*) as NUM FROM `items` WHERE `modified` BETWEEN '$day1 00:00:00' AND '$day2 23:59:59';";}



        elseif($service==3){

$query = "SELECT COUNT(*) as NUM FROM `items` WHERE `modified` BETWEEN '$day1 00:00:00' AND '$day2 23:59:59';";}

$result = mysql_query($query,$conn);

  $num = mysql_fetch_array ($result);

  return $num['NUM'];

}
```

Comment: Am I missing something or is there really no difference in your queries?

Comment: In all three cases $query contains the same string ...is that intentional?

Comment: What are the values of $day1, $day2 and $service? Can you echo them?

Comment: what are the values of $day1 and $day2 , they should be like ex '2010-03-31' ... if not your query-result will be empty... also, the  trailing ; in your query is not needed...

Comment: The queries are the same right now...I should have fixed them before posting, sorry.

Comment: @hypnocode: Actually with *ZERO*, do you mean **0** (number zero) or **NULL** ? Or maybe even an empty string?

Comment: I mean 0, the number.  It's supposed to show up on Open Flash Chart.  It shows up 0 there and shows up 0 when I echo.  SQL statements work fine on MySQL query tool.

Comment: Yes, $day1 and $day2 are the correct format.  $service is a constant I defined: define("CONT_ALL_SERVICE",1);

Comment: What does a `var_dump($num);` give you?

Comment: @Felix array(2) {[0]  =>  string(1) "0" ["NUM"]=>  string(1) "0" }

Comment: @hypnocode: Ok, I just wanted to verify that. Next try: **Are you sure that `$conn` is a connection to the right database?** :)

Comment: Yeah, $conn is working for the rest of my functions.

Comment: WAIT!  I think I know what's wrong...it's passing in the wrong date for some reason.

Answer (score 3):

Try some debug output in your function, e.g.

```
function getCountBetweenDays($day1,$day2,$service)
{
  global $conn;

  switch($service) {
    case 1:
      $query = "SELECT COUNT(*) as NUM FROM `items` WHERE `modified` BETWEEN '$day1 00:00:00' AND '$day2 23:59:59'";
      break;
    case 2:
      $query = "SELECT COUNT(*) as NUM FROM `items` WHERE `modified` BETWEEN '$day1 00:00:00' AND '$day2 23:59:59'";
      break;
    case 3:
      $query = "SELECT COUNT(*) as NUM FROM `items` WHERE `modified` BETWEEN '$day1 00:00:00' AND '$day2 23:59:59'";
      break;
    default:
      die('unknown value for $service');
  }

  echo '<pre>Debug: $query=', htmlspecialchars($query), '</pre>';
  $result = mysql_query($query,$conn) or die('mysql_query failed: '.htmlspecialchars(mysql_error($conn)));
  echo '<pre>Debug: numrows=', mysql_num_rows($result), '</pre>';
  $num = mysql_fetch_array($result);

  return $num['NUM'];
}
```

Comment: this covers too much of his code but still +1 he will get the error eventually at the end, he'd be faster of changing "suspicious" bits of code

Comment: I hope it "resembles" the original function just enough to be "comprehensible" ;-) Keep in mind that you usually neither want to bail out so quickly (using die()) nor reveal the actual mysql error string to each and every user in production code ...it's just an example.

Comment: And thanks for adding the switch...I never knew you could do that in PHP.

Comment: Thanks!  This is getting me closer...for some reason it's just passing in a year for the date.  I'll let you know if I find a solution.

Comment: Thank you very much, this helped me find out what was going wrong.  I posted my solution. I would vote this up, but I don't have 15 rep points yet.

Answer (score 1):

For starters, add

```
if (!$result) echo mysql_error();
```

after each `mysql_query()` call to see whether there are any errors. I'm pretty sure there are.

Comment: @Pekka sorry still upset at someone down voting me in like 20 sec .. didn't read it properly

Comment: Should I put this after EVERY mysql_query() to see the error?

Comment: Nothing, I put them after each one.

Comment: If you don't like that use PDO ( http://docs.php.net/pdo ) and set `$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);`. Then an exception is thrown each time something goes wrong. Not everybody likes exceptions, but imo at least it's a bit harder to "ignore" them or to forget the error handling.

Comment: Thanks, I'll add it to my list of things to try.

Answer (score 1):

Your queries are not formatter properly they are :

```
"SELECT COUNT(*) as NUM FROM `items` WHERE `modified` BETWEEN '$day1 00:00:00' AND '$day2 23:59:59';";
```

They should be :

```
"SELECT COUNT(*) as NUM FROM `items` WHERE `modified` BETWEEN '$day1 00:00:00' AND '$day2 23:59:59'";
```

You have an extra semi-colon in each query. and use `or die mysql_error()` to print out the error.

Also this part :

```
$num = mysql_fetch_array ($result);

  return $num['NUM'];
```

I'd replaced with :

```
$num = mysql_fetch_array ($result);

extract($num);

  return $NUM;//if this is your field name
```

Comment: That is proper SQL. It delimited queries. While it is not necessary, it is not the cause of the problem.

Comment: This shouldn't be a problem. `;` is the query deliminator.

Comment: why the minus vote I'm offering a man few solutions, give guy something instead of just minusing voted dammit

Comment: @c0mrade: I agree that some people are very fast in downvoting other answers...sometimes this is really ridiculous.

Comment: yea .. so far I've given up offering some more solutions .. I simply don't care anymore to write anythign .. peace

Comment: Because your 'solution' will just waste the OP's time.

Comment: What's the point of using extract()? I would understand using mysql\_result() since it's a single row with only one value, but extract()?

Comment: @c0mrade: a downvote is nothing personal. It's just a sign that someone disagrees with the answer, and it was totally justified in your case. But hey, don't take it too seriously. It's just a game.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed it...dumb mistake.  I'm so new to PHP and MySQL, sorry.

```
getCountBetweenDays(2010-3-1,2010-3-28,CONT_ALL_SERVICE);
```

should have been:

```
getTweetCountBetweenDays('2010-3-1','2010-3-28',CONT_ALL_SERVICE);
```

Thanks all for the help and I now know how to debug properly!

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to reference a numeric index [n] with an associative index ['s']. Either specify  this to your query

```
mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_BOTH)
```

Or just do

```
mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
```

Which will let you reference indices by association

Answer (score -1):

> return $num['NUM'];

means return the 'num' part of the array; Change 'NUM' to 1 or 2 and then try

Comment: `mysql_fetch_array()` returns an array with both column numbers AND column names. `mysql_fetch_assoc()` returns only an array with column names.

Comment: @NebNeb Nope, `mysql_fetch_array` fetches both the numeric and the associative part by default.

Comment: By default, `mysql_fetch_array` returns the result as numerical **and** associative array. So the array access should work imo.